# TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not TrainingResult

Tags: jupyter-notebook, rasa, deeppavlov

this is my code :

```
from rasa.jupyter import chat 
endpoints = "endpoints.yml"
chat(model_path, endpoints)
```

It gives Error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 2
> 3 endpoints = "endpoints.yml"
> ----> 4 chat(model_path, endpoints)

C:\anaconda\envs\newrasa\lib\site-packages\rasa\jupyter.py in chat(model_path, endpoints, agent, interpreter)
35         from rasa.run import create_agent
36
---> 37         agent = create_agent(model_path, endpoints)
38
39     elif agent is not None and interpreter is not None:

C:\anaconda\envs\newrasa\lib\site-packages\rasa\run.py in create_agent(model, endpoints)
72     _lock_store = LockStore.create(_endpoints.lock_store)
73
---> 74     return Agent.load(
75         model,
76         generator=_endpoints.nlg,

C:\anaconda\envs\newrasa\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\agent.py in load(cls, model_path, interpreter, generator, tracker_store, lock_store, action_endpoint, model_server, remote_storage, path_to_model_archive, new_config, finetuning_epoch_fraction)
414             if not model_path:
415                 raise ModelNotFound("No path specified.")
--> 416             if not os.path.exists(model_path):
417                 raise ModelNotFound(f"No file or directory at '{model_path}'.")
418             if os.path.isfile(model_path):

C:\anaconda\envs\newrasa\lib\genericpath.py in exists(path)
17     """Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links"""
18     try:
---> 19         os.stat(path)
20     except (OSError, ValueError):
21         return False

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not TrainingResult

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that the function expects a string containing the path to the generated tar.gz, and not an object. The path is in `model_path.model`

Answer (score -2):

```
chat(model_path.model, endpoints)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.